# Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've a couple of scenarios in my WP8 where I'm getting this exception message :
*"Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications."*
 Both of these scenarios have *async* calls. I want to know in general when do I get such an exception, so that I understand what to look for whenever I get them. Is that possible to know or I need to describe my particular scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a pretty generic message meaning you did something wrong with your XAML.  If you're dynamically creating controls, review your code in detail to make sure you're doing it properly.  For instance, as in my case, when assigning names to dynamically built controls, make sure each time you assign a different name if the same code is building multiple controls.

Answer (score 0):

I am the guy who upvoted your question as I had a similar problem. The solution was so simple I could hardly believe it when I found out. Syntax error in my XAML. I declared `FontSize="20px"` instead of `FontSize="20"`. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xaml.

I had this error when I inserted DataTemplate inside a DataTemplate.

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="ExerciseNamesTemplate">
       <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Hope it helps