# Xamarin.forms windows phone - out of browser specific settings do not affect in-browser application

Tags: forms, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

i have 2 xaml pages and try to select an image on 1 , and set it on the other page. It all works fine on android but produces an error on windows phone.
I use the Plugin.media plugin to select images.(https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media)

i have this function to select an image:

```
async void OnPictoChoose(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (!removing) 
        {
            //create the new image and entry and the stacklayout to hold them
            Image chosenImage = (Image)sender;
            Label chosenLabel = new Label ();
            StackLayout currentStack = new StackLayout ();

            //find the stacklayout that holds the chosen image and store in currentStack, we need this to find the correct label/entry
            foreach (StackLayout stack in pictoTheek.Children) 
            {
                foreach (var child in stack.Children.OfType<Image>()) 
                {
                    if (child == chosenImage) 
                    {
                        currentStack = stack;
                    }
                }
            }

            //find the entry that belongs to the image in the currentStack and store it in chosenLabel
            foreach (var child in currentStack.Children.OfType<Label>()) 
            {
                chosenLabel = child;
            }

            //find the root page at the top of the navigationStack
            MyPage stepPage = (MyPage)Navigation.NavigationStack [0];
            //set the image and label with the method on the steppage using the chosenImage and chosenLabel
            stepPage.SetImageAndLabel (chosenImage, chosenLabel);
            //close the pictotheek
            await Navigation.PopAsync ();
        }
```

as you can see I call the SetImageAndLabel on the steppage which looks like this:

```
public void SetImageAndLabel(Image pictotheekImg, Label pictptheekLabel)
    {
        //create stacklayout as placeholder to find the Label
        StackLayout currentStack = new StackLayout();

        //find the currentstack by looking for the selectedimage in the scrollsteps,
        foreach (StackLayout child in scrollSteps.Children) 
        {
            //set the selected image to the image chosen in the pictotheek
            foreach (Image item in child.Children.OfType<Image>()) 
            {
                if (item == selectedImage) 
                {
                    currentStack = child;
                    item.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
                    item.Source = pictotheekImg.Source; 
                }
            }

            //find the label that belongs to the selectedimage in the currentStack and set the text
            foreach (Label label in currentStack.Children.OfType<Label>()) 
            {
                label.Text = pictptheekLabel.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is in the line item.Source = pictotheekImg.Source, which produces :  'this.MainWindow' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'.

the inner-exception sais ""null", it does have a message which sais:
"out of browser specific settings do not affect in-browser application"

page 1

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Lisa.Ruben.MyPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout>
          <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
           <StackLayout Orientation = "Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Orientation = "Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="scrollSteps" Padding="31,0,31,0"  VerticalOptions="Center">
             <!-- dynamicly added images come here -->
            </StackLayout>
           </StackLayout>
          </ScrollView>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Silver" HeightRequest="75" >
           <Button Text = "Add New Step" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="AddNewStep" WidthRequest="200"/>
           <Button Text = "Remove Step" Clicked="OnRemoveButtonClick" WidthRequest="200" x:Name="removeButton"/>
          </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

page2:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Lisa.Ruben.PictotheekPage">
 <ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
   <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="pictoScroll">
        <StackLayout Orientation = "Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="15,15,0,20"  x:Name="pictoTheek">
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="alien.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226"  VerticalOptions="Center">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
         <Label Text="alien" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />       
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout> 
            <Image Source="levelup.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226" VerticalOptions="Center" >
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="level up" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="bloem.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226" VerticalOptions="Center" >
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="bloem" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="mario.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226" VerticalOptions="Center">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="mario" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="chrome.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226" VerticalOptions="Center">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="chrome" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
           </StackLayout>
           <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="circle.jpg" WidthRequest="260" HeightRequest="226" VerticalOptions="Center">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnPictoChoose"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
           <Label Text="circle" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
      </ScrollView>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Silver" HeightRequest="75" x:Name="buttonBar">
    <Button Text = "Add New Picto" Clicked="AddNewPicto" WidthRequest="150" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Button Text = "Create New Picto" Clicked="CreateNewPicto" WidthRequest="150" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Button Text = "Remove Picto" Clicked="OnRemovePictoClick" WidthRequest="150" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="removePictoButton"/>
         </StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Did you set the permissions, such as IC_CAP_ISV_CAMERA or Webcam? On Windows Phone 8.1 RT you also need to add Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.OnFilesPicked(args); in App.xaml.cs

Comment: i tried adding the line Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.OnFilesPicked(args); but i said mediaimplementation does not contain a definition for "OnFilesPicked",
where exactly do i put this? i also cannot find where i can set the IC_CAP_ISV_CAMERA permission, can you tell me where this is?

Comment: It depends. If your project is Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight then you need to go to the WMAppManifest (check http://lh3.ggpht.com/-vkIKDE2wspk/Ut_jhfo44zI/AAAAAAAAOTQ/YRZvq2r-BT0/Enable%252520the%252520ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA%252520Capability%252520in%252520Windows%252520Phone%252520application%25255B5%25255D.png?imgmax=800). If your project is Windows Phone 8.1 RT or Windows Store then you set Webcam permission instead. Which Windows Phone project are you using, 8/8.1 Silverlight, Store or 8.1 RT?

Comment: i use an 8.1 silverlight phone, i tried setting the IC_CAP_ISV_CAMERA permission but i still get the same error

Comment: I just searched for the exception message and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408758/out-of-browser-specific-settings-do-not-affect-in-browser-applications It is a generic message which says that there's an error in your XAML. Please check it in case of any mistake or update your question with your XAML code so we can help :)

Comment: i had already seen that question, but i dont think there is anything wrong with my xaml, as it does build and runs on android, but i updated the question with my xaml so you can take a look, thanks for the interest:)

Comment: @Luis Beltran, Hi, did you already have time to check out my xaml? I'm really stuck on this right now,and you are th only one replying, I'm even willing to send you the entire app so you can check it out